# Error 550001 User is not allowed to perform this action - Adaptive Parallel Payments

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

After trying to use the sandbox and constantly getting the following error:

```
php error message = fopen(https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
```

I decided I'd switch to the Live environment. However, when I try to perform a Parallel Adaptive Payment (using a third party plugin for Magento), I always get the 550001 error (User is not allowed to perform this action).

According to what I read elsewhere, I've checked that my PayPal Business account is verified (though I haven't got a definitve proof of that - how would I do that?), that my credentials are correct (using [this URL](https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp?&user=xxxxxxxxxx&pwd=xxxxxxxxxx&signature=xxxxxxxxxx&version=70.0&METHOD=SetExpressCheckout&RETURNURL=http://www.paypal.com/test.php&CANCELURL=http://www.paypal.com/test.php&PAYMENTACTION=Sale&AMT=50&CURRENCYCODE=USD)) and that my application included the Basic Payment permissions. Still not working.

What else should I check?

Answer (score 0):

For Adaptive payments your application needs approval from PayPal.

For more information [click here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/goingLive/) and search for "Reviewing applications with Adaptive API calls"

Comment: I've already had my application approved. I learned from documentation that Chained Payments require an approval process, but Parallel Payments are easily allowed and an application with Parallel and/or Basic Payments is automatically approved (which is what happened to mine).